# Objective-C memory leak when returning NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, memory-management, memory-leaks

I want to be sure that my code is not leaking, since this small snippet is called thousand times in my app. I run the app through Instruments and the initWithBytes seems to be problematic. Is anything wrong in this code?

First [reader readString] is called.

```
case FirstCase:
{       
    NSString *string = [reader readString];
    [self setPropertyByName:propertyName value:string];
    break;
}
...
```

readString is returns the strings which is autoreleased.

```
- (NSString*) readString
 {
       ...
       NSString *string = [[[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cursor length:stringLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];         
      return string;
}
```

Is the code OK? Any other better approach to avoid autorelease?

I cannot change my code to ARC. Plain old non-ARC memory management.

Comment: why aren't you using ARC

Comment: I agree with Bryan. Please do yourself a favour and read up on ARC, it was introduced in iOS 4 and there is absolutely no reason why you should not be using it.

Comment: Please post whole `readString` method, the last two lines look OK.

Comment: ARC is going to be used in the near future. I cannot use it with a last minute patch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is OK. The only rule at this point is that methods contain "create" or "alloc" will return an object that needs to be explicitly released. In your case that is the string returned in the `readString` method.

Since the object will be returned you need to retain it till the end of the run loop cycle which the autorelease pool will do. What that means for instance is if this method will be called in a `for` loop the objects will not be deallocated before the loop has exited.

If you want or need to avoid that I suggest you to do the same pattern with "create" or "alloc" and return an object not being autoreleased:

```
case FirstCase:
{       
    NSString *string = [reader createReadString];
    [self setPropertyByName:propertyName value:string];
    [string release];
    break;
}
...


- (NSString*) createReadString
{
       ...
       NSString *string = [[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:cursor length:stringLength encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];         
      return string;
}
```

Comment: Looks better this way. Do I need to check if string exists before releasing?, ie (if string) [string release];

Comment: No. If you call any method on a nil object simply nothing will happen. So it is already done for you. Just to be clear if the method is returning a value and is called on a nil object a 0 will be returned which can be interpreted as nil, NULL, NO, false...

Comment: I am asking, because a received a "message sent to deallocated instance" after modifying the code

Comment: Then the object was already deallocated. Please recheck all release or autorelease calls on the object. For debugging you may use retainCount property to check where it failed. Once this value hits zero the object will be deallocated.

Comment: After static analysis I get this: incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by caller

Comment: That is because the static analysis does look for the create rule in your own methods. You will always get that warning but it is correct anyway. These should come in pairs though: You should be getting a warning in the create method as well. Since you are not it would imply you are releasing the string in the create method. Did you remove the autorelease call as it is essential? Essential to remove that is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78433/discussion-between-cateof-and-matic-oblak).